# dart changes runtimetype from List<Superclass> to List<Class> without any reason

Tags: flutter, dart

I have these 3 classes:

```
class Parent() {}
class Child() extends Parent {}
class Sibling() extends Parent {}
```

I have a list of `Parent` through this code:

```
List<Parent> items = [];
items = await futureFnc.getItems(); // <-- This function returns List<Parent>
```

The function `getItems` returns a `List<Parent>`, but in my example all items returned are `Child` type.

If I try this code:

```
items.add(Sibling());
```

I get this error:

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Sibling' is not a subtype of type 'Child' of 'value'

If I check `items.runtimeType` value, I get `List<Child>` instead of expected `List<Parent>`.

Any clue?

Comment: can you share your full code?

Comment: getItems might be typed as return List<Parent>, but if it returns a List<Child>, that complies with the contract, and "items" will then be holding a List<Child>, not a List<Parent>.  You can downcast the return value from getItems with `as List<Parent>`, I think.  Or, you can do items.addAll(getItems()) which will not change the container from the original List<Parent>.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I already tried to downcast the return value of the function, without success. Instead with `addAll` it worked. Thank you.

Comment: I'm certain it was something else in your code; `items.add(Sibling())` should work without explicit down-casting.

Comment: What is the implementation of `getItems`?  Fix it to explicitly return a `<Parent>[...]` instead of returning a `List` with what's probably an inferred element type.

Comment: @sleepystar96 No, `items.add(Sibling())` will not work if `getItems` returns a `List` with a *runtime* type of `List<Child>` but a *static* type of `List<Parent>`.

Comment: @jamesdlin It works fine: https://replit.com/@SleepyStar/getItems#main.dart

Comment: @sleepystar96 There is no object with a runtime type of `List<Child>` in your example, so it does not demonstrate the scenario I described.  Try replacing `return [Parent()];` with `var list = [Child()]; return list;`.

Comment: @jamesdlin you're right, but then downcasting `var list = [Child() as Parent];` works fine. See my updated code, if `futureFnc.getItems()` was returning Future<Parent> type on runtime, it wouldn't have an issue; so.. it's something in their code that is not right.

Comment: In other words, it's not fair to use `var list = [Child()]` in this example, because `list` would be allocated as `List<Child>` in memory. It's comparing to very different things.

Comment: @sleepystar96 How isn't it fair?  That's the problem that the OP is encountering!  The OP unwittingly created a `List<Child>` even though they expected a `List<Parent>`.    The point is that the code will encounter a runtime error despite passing static analysis without warnings and without doing any explicit up- or down-casts.  Yes, "their code isn't right", but it's not obviously wrong either.

Comment: Their code is returning `List<Child>` when it should be returning `List<Parent>`, hence it isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using `addAll` to starting list instead of assign the value returned from the function.

This works:

```
List<Parent> items = [];
items.addAll(await futureFnc.getItems());
```

Now if I check `items.runtimeType` I get `List<Parent>`